# Low Variables parsing grid

Tags: solspace-freeform, stash, low-variables, low, parsing

I'm using Low Variables. This specific variable is of the type 'Grid'.
What I'm having in my template is this:

`<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
  {exp:low_variables:pair var="var_eleads_country"}
     <option value="{var_eleads_country:code}">{var_eleads_country:label}</option>
  {/exp:low_variables:pair}
</select>`

In my actual template though, it doesn't work. I'm only seeing one option, with {var_eleads_country:code} as value and {var_eleads_country:label} as text.

What should I do?

EDIT: This is happening inside of a Freeform. Also, I'm using Croxton's Stash. This is the stash_template, but the Form itself is wrappen in a {stash:nocache}.

Comment: You've got a missing closing } there. Are you sure that's not it?

Comment: Must be something that went wrong while copy pasting, but it's there in my actual template.

Comment: Edited and added some more info on this

Comment: And are you sure "label" is a valid Grid column name?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure :)
In the actual case, my fields are code, en, fr and es, but I simplified it here.

The issue is in the looping, there's about 50 countries in this grid, but the parsed html is only like this:
`<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
  <option value="{var_eleads_country:code}">{var_eleads_country:en}</option>
 </select>`

Comment: My god, I'm ashamed to say this, but I made a type indeed. 'var_eleads_country' should have been 'var_eleads_countries'. However, it had some issues still, that I point out in my solution below. Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I did a fix.

I renamed my en, fr and es fields with a prefix label_.

In my template I did this:

`{/stash:nocache}
 {exp:low_variables:parse var="var_eleads_countries"}
      <option value="{var_eleads_countries:code}">   {var_eleads_countries:label_{segment_1}}</option>
  {/exp:low_variables:parse}
{stash:nocache}`

The nocache tag is wrapped around my form, but it's important to close it and reopen it when parsing here, because otherwise, you'll have parsing issues on the {segment_1} tag.

Also, I fixed my typ in the var (*insert shame here*), which had to be var_eleads_countries rather than var_eleads_country.